# AWS Bill Generation Time in GMT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to know at what time amazon updates the reports that are created in s3 buckets. Is it updated on midnight? Want to know the exact time in GMT

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: I want to fetch billing data programmatically into my local storage through a job. if i know the exact time, i can schedule my job on that particular time.

Comment: You can check the object's metadata in S3 itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking back at 1+ year of billing reports, it doesn't look like you should *expect* that the billing reports will be generated at a specific time.

This makes perfect sense. Even if some background job was always **triggered** at some specific time (and this is probably an oversimplification for such a complex billing system), I can't assume even Amazon would be able to guarantee that ALL these background jobs (i.e. for ALL customers) would finish at the same time every time they run.

There is always a different data set + other ongoing workload to consider, which would certainly affect the completion time.

FWIW, I am including a screenshot from my S3 bucket:
 [image: aws billing report times]

Comment: Google Cloud is even worse. You can't even expect to get it every day. They only care that the lines are reported, not when. So sometimes your daily file can lack some lines, which then appear in the file one or two days later. The lesson is that we should probably model reading of these files as importing lines, not files, and that the reporting will be eventually consistent (with a few days delay).